# OpenCV - Color blob detector with different color

Tags: android, opencv

`How to apply different`color`on`camera`frame in color blob detector opencv app? I have done applying different color on blob using`drawcontour` with contour id. But I couldn't achieve the functionality of when the user click on any pixel and apply color only withing the edge then click on another area to apply different color, even the camera frame is resetting on every touch.

Answer (score 0):

The color blob sample with Open CV is designed to find all the blobs of a single color in a camera frame.

At the moment, when the screen is touched the color is stored in the variable 'mBlobColorHsv' in the ColorBlobDetectionActivity and the ColorBlobDetetor Object is set up to detect this color via its 'setHVSColor' method.

If you wanted to find first one color and then another you would need to modify the sample program to add each detected color to a list of detected colours every time the screen is touched, and update the ColorBlobDetetor object to store and detect a list of colors.